# what are definitions of born or die (birth-death point) and crossing point?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, definitions, critical-point-theory

in this [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/0040938380900099?token=52EC9258830E33764ED96D53167D9285E49D70462F1BD27275053E4AF4528419683EA5B61606B52FD43BF327B5524D11&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20211228150620) we have :

**A presentation for the mapping class group of a closed orientable surface.by Hatcher.W.Thurston**

...(a) $f_{t_{0}}$ has exactly one degenerate critical point, of the form $f_{t}(x, y)=$ $x^{3} \pm\left(t-t_{0}\right) x \pm y^{2}$. As $t$ passes $t_{0}$, a pair of non-degenerate critical points of adjacent indices are **born or die (birth-death point)**.
(b) $f_{t}$ has two non-degenerate critical points whose critical values reverse order as $t$ passes $t_{0}$ (**crossing point**).

A helpful picture is the graphic of $f_{t},\left\{\left(f_{t}(x), t\right) \mid x\right.$ is a critical point of $\left.f_{t}\right\} .$ For example, see Fig. 3. At a **birth-death point**, $\Gamma\left(f_{t}\right)$ changes as in Fig. $4 .$

It is not hard to see that $\Gamma\left(f_{t}\right)$ changes at a **crossing point** only if both critical points are of index one, and they belong to the same component of the level set of $f_{t_{0}}$ which contains them .

> what are definitions of **born or die (birth-death point)** and  **crossing point** ?

[image]

Comment: The definitions of those terms are the preceding test that you quoted.

Comment: @KevinWalker . I can't understand.  Please give me more details.